# Can't set breadcrumbs manual to JS. To low level.

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Нi everyone! 
I use https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/17/multi-level-menu/ project to create a php site. 
It's work's awesome. I use history.pushState() to set history. For example, when user select category i set link like //site.com/?category=5. The problem is when user refresh page... content loads good, it's use $_GET['category'] and Mysql to make it, but i need to set breadcrumbs manualy to js... How i can do it? This JS code is too hard for my js level. =( Any help? Thx.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Main container -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Menu toggle for mobile version -->
    <button class="action action--open" aria-label="Open Menu"><span class="icon icon--menu"></span></button>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <nav id="ml-menu" class="menu">
        <!-- Close button for mobile version -->
        <button class="action action--close" aria-label="Close Menu"><span class="icon icon--cross"></span></button>
        <div class="menu__wrap">
            <ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1" href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-2" href="#">Fruits</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-3" href="#">Grains</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-4" href="#">Mylk & Drinks</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 1 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-1" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Stalk Vegetables</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Roots & Seeds</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Cabbages</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Salad Greens</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Mushrooms</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1-1" href="#">Sale %</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 1-1 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-1-1" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Fair Trade Roots</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Dried Veggies</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Our Brand</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Homemade</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 2 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-2" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Citrus Fruits</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Berries</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-2-1" href="#">Special Selection</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Tropical Fruits</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Melons</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 2-1 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-2-1" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Exotic Mixes</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Wild Pick</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Vitamin Boosters</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 3 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-3" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Buckwheat</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Millet</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Quinoa</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Wild Rice</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Durum Wheat</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-3-1" href="#">Promo Packs</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 3-1 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-3-1" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Starter Kit</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">The Essential 8</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Bolivian Secrets</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Flour Packs</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 4 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-4" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Grain Mylks</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Seed Mylks</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Nut Mylks</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Nutri Drinks</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-4-1" href="#">Selection</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Submenu 4-1 -->
            <ul data-menu="submenu-4-1" class="menu__level">
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Nut Mylk Packs</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Amino Acid Heaven</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Allergy Free</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="info">Please choose a category</p>
        <!-- Ajax loaded content here -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /view -->
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/dummydata.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    var menuEl = document.getElementById('ml-menu'),
        mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {
            // breadcrumbsCtrl : true, // show breadcrumbs
            // initialBreadcrumb : 'all', // initial breadcrumb text
            backCtrl : false, // show back button
            // itemsDelayInterval : 60, // delay between each menu item sliding animation
            onItemClick: loadDummyData // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked - onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
        });

    // mobile menu toggle
    var openMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--open'),
        closeMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--close');

    openMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
    closeMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);

    function openMenu() {
        classie.add(menuEl, 'menu--open');
    }

    function closeMenu() {
        classie.remove(menuEl, 'menu--open');
    }

    // simulate grid content loading
    var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');

    function loadDummyData(ev, itemName) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        closeMenu();
        gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
        classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
            classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
            gridWrapper.innerHTML = '<ul class="products">' + dummyData[itemName] + '<ul>';
        }, 700);
    }
})();
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
* Icons (made with Icomoon.io) */
/* Feather Icons by Cole Bemis */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'feather';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/feather/feather.eot?1gafuo');
    src: url('../fonts/feather/feather.eot?1gafuo#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/feather/feather.woff2?1gafuo') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/feather/feather.ttf?1gafuo') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/feather/feather.woff?1gafuo') format('woff'), url('../fonts/feather/feather.svg?1gafuo#feather') format('svg');
}

.icon {
    font-family: 'feather';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    speak: none;
}

.icon--arrow-left:before {
    content: '\e901';
}

.icon--menu:before {
    content: '\e903';
}

.icon--cross:before {
    content: '\e117';
} 


/* Menu styles */

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    background: #1c1d22;
}

.menu__wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.5em;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu__level {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: calc(100% + 50px);
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__level--current {
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu__item {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.menu__link {
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 2.5em 1em 1.5em;
    color: #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s;
    transition: color 0.1s;
}

.menu__link[data-submenu]::after {
    content: '\e904';
    font-family: 'feather';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0.25em 1.25em;
    color: #2a2b30;
}

.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link[data-submenu]:hover::after {
    color: #5c5edc;
}

.menu__link--current::before {
    content: '\00B7';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0.5em;
    height: 4px;
    color: #5c5edc;
}

[class^='animate-'],
[class*=' animate-'] {
    visibility: visible;
}

.animate-outToRight .menu__item {
    -webkit-animation: outToRight 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    animation: outToRight 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes outToRight {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes outToRight {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

.animate-outToLeft .menu__item {
    -webkit-animation: outToLeft 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    animation: outToLeft 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes outToLeft {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes outToLeft {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

.animate-inFromLeft .menu__item {
    -webkit-animation: inFromLeft 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    animation: inFromLeft 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes inFromLeft {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes inFromLeft {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.animate-inFromRight .menu__item {
    -webkit-animation: inFromRight 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    animation: inFromRight 0.6s both cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes inFromRight {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes inFromRight {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.menu__breadcrumbs {
    font-size: 0.65em;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2.5em 3.75em 1.5em 2.5em;
}

.menu__breadcrumbs a {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #5c5edc;
}

.menu__breadcrumbs a:last-child {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu__breadcrumbs a:hover {
    color: #8182e0;
}

.menu__breadcrumbs a:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '\e902';
    font-family: 'feather';
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    color: #33353e;
}

.menu__breadcrumbs a:not(:last-child):hover::after {
    color: #33353e;
}

.menu__back {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    right: 2.25em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.365em 0.65em 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2a2b30;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

.menu__back--hidden {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu__back:hover,
.menu__back:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
}


/* Open and close buttons */

.action {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

.action:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.action--open {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.action--close {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 1.25em;
    right: 1em;
    display: none;
    color: #45464e;
}

/* Example media query */
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .action--open,
    .action--close {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu {
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
        transition: transform 0.3s;
    }
    .menu--open {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
;(function(window) {

    'use strict';

    var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
        animEndEventNames = { 'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd', 'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd', 'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd', 'animation' : 'animationend' },
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
        onEndAnimation = function( el, callback ) {
            var onEndCallbackFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.animations ) {
                    if( ev.target != this ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
                }
                if( callback && typeof callback === 'function' ) { callback.call(); }
            };
            if( support.animations ) {
                el.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndCallbackFn();
            }
        };

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function MLMenu(el, options) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );

        // the menus (
´s)
        this.menus = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('.menu__level'));
        // index of current menu
        this.current = 0;

        this._init();
    }

    MLMenu.prototype.options = {
        // show breadcrumbs
        breadcrumbsCtrl : true,
        // initial breadcrumb text
        initialBreadcrumb : 'all',
        // show back button
        backCtrl : true,
        // delay between each menu item sliding animation
        itemsDelayInterval : 60,
        // direction 
        direction : 'r2l',
        // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked
        // onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
        onItemClick : function(ev, itemName) { return false; }
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._init = function() {
        // iterate the existing menus and create an array of menus, more specifically an array of objects where each one holds the info of each menu element and its menu items
        this.menusArr = [];
        var self = this;
        this.menus.forEach(function(menuEl, pos) {
            var menu = {menuEl : menuEl, menuItems : [].slice.call(menuEl.querySelectorAll('.menu__item'))};
            self.menusArr.push(menu);

            // set current menu class
            if( pos === self.current ) {
                classie.add(menuEl, 'menu__level--current');
            }
        });

        // create back button
        if( this.options.backCtrl ) {
            this.backCtrl = document.createElement('button');
            this.backCtrl.className = 'menu__back menu__back--hidden';
            this.backCtrl.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Go back');
            this.backCtrl.innerHTML = '';
            this.el.insertBefore(this.backCtrl, this.el.firstChild);
        }


        // create breadcrumbs
        if( self.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
            this.breadcrumbsCtrl = document.createElement('nav');
            this.breadcrumbsCtrl.className = 'menu__breadcrumbs';
            this.el.insertBefore(this.breadcrumbsCtrl, this.el.firstChild);
            // add initial breadcrumb
            this._addBreadcrumb(0);
        }

        // event binding
        this._initEvents();
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        for(var i = 0, len = this.menusArr.length; i < len; ++i) {
            this.menusArr[i].menuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
                item.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(ev) { 
                    var submenu = ev.target.getAttribute('data-submenu'),
                        itemName = ev.target.innerHTML,
                        subMenuEl = self.el.querySelector('ul[data-menu="' + submenu + '"]');

                    // check if there's a sub menu for this item
                    if( submenu && subMenuEl ) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        // open it
                        self._openSubMenu(subMenuEl, pos, itemName);
                    }
                    else {
                        // add class current
                        var currentlink = self.el.querySelector('.menu__link--current');
                        if( currentlink ) {
                            classie.remove(self.el.querySelector('.menu__link--current'), 'menu__link--current');
                        }
                        classie.add(ev.target, 'menu__link--current');

                        // callback
                        self.options.onItemClick(ev, itemName);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // back navigation
        if( this.options.backCtrl ) {
            this.backCtrl.addEventListener('click', function() {
                self._back();
            });
        }
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._openSubMenu = function(subMenuEl, clickPosition, subMenuName) {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        // save "parent" menu index for back navigation
        this.menusArr[this.menus.indexOf(subMenuEl)].backIdx = this.current;
        // save "parent" menu´s name
        this.menusArr[this.menus.indexOf(subMenuEl)].name = subMenuName;
        // current menu slides out
        this._menuOut(clickPosition);
        // next menu (submenu) slides in
        this._menuIn(subMenuEl, clickPosition);
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._back = function() {
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;

        // current menu slides out
        this._menuOut();
        // next menu (previous menu) slides in
        var backMenu = this.menusArr[this.menusArr[this.current].backIdx].menuEl;
        this._menuIn(backMenu);

        // remove last breadcrumb
        if( this.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
            this.breadcrumbsCtrl.removeChild(this.breadcrumbsCtrl.lastElementChild);
        }
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._menuOut = function(clickPosition) {
        // the current menu
        var self = this,
            currentMenu = this.menusArr[this.current].menuEl,
            isBackNavigation = typeof clickPosition == 'undefined' ? true : false;

        // slide out current menu items - first, set the delays for the items
        this.menusArr[this.current].menuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
            item.style.WebkitAnimationDelay = item.style.animationDelay = isBackNavigation ? parseInt(pos * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms' : parseInt(Math.abs(clickPosition - pos) * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms';
        });
        // animation class
        if( this.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
            classie.add(currentMenu, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
        }
        else {
            classie.add(currentMenu, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');    
        }
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._menuIn = function(nextMenuEl, clickPosition) {
        var self = this,
            // the current menu
            currentMenu = this.menusArr[this.current].menuEl,
            isBackNavigation = typeof clickPosition == 'undefined' ? true : false,
            // index of the nextMenuEl
            nextMenuIdx = this.menus.indexOf(nextMenuEl),

            nextMenuItems = this.menusArr[nextMenuIdx].menuItems,
            nextMenuItemsTotal = nextMenuItems.length;

        // slide in next menu items - first, set the delays for the items
        nextMenuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
            item.style.WebkitAnimationDelay = item.style.animationDelay = isBackNavigation ? parseInt(pos * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms' : parseInt(Math.abs(clickPosition - pos) * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms';

            // we need to reset the classes once the last item animates in
            // the "last item" is the farthest from the clicked item
            // let's calculate the index of the farthest item
            var farthestIdx = clickPosition <= nextMenuItemsTotal/2 || isBackNavigation ? nextMenuItemsTotal - 1 : 0;

            if( pos === farthestIdx ) {
                onEndAnimation(item, function() {
                    // reset classes
                    if( self.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
                        classie.remove(currentMenu, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
                        classie.remove(nextMenuEl, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
                    }
                    else {
                        classie.remove(currentMenu, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
                        classie.remove(nextMenuEl, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
                    }
                    classie.remove(currentMenu, 'menu__level--current');
                    classie.add(nextMenuEl, 'menu__level--current');

                    //reset current
                    self.current = nextMenuIdx;

                    // control back button and breadcrumbs navigation elements
                    if( !isBackNavigation ) {
                        // show back button
                        if( self.options.backCtrl ) {
                            classie.remove(self.backCtrl, 'menu__back--hidden');
                        }

                        // add breadcrumb
                        self._addBreadcrumb(nextMenuIdx);
                    }
                    else if( self.current === 0 && self.options.backCtrl ) {
                        // hide back button
                        classie.add(self.backCtrl, 'menu__back--hidden');
                    }

                    // we can navigate again..
                    self.isAnimating = false;
                });
            }
        }); 

        // animation class
        if( this.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
            classie.add(nextMenuEl, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
        }
        else {
            classie.add(nextMenuEl, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
        }
    };

    MLMenu.prototype._addBreadcrumb = function(idx) {
        if( !this.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
            return false;
        }

        var bc = document.createElement('a');
        bc.innerHTML = idx ? this.menusArr[idx].name : this.options.initialBreadcrumb;
        this.breadcrumbsCtrl.appendChild(bc);

        var self = this;
        bc.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            // do nothing if this breadcrumb is the last one in the list of breadcrumbs
            if( !bc.nextSibling || self.isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            self.isAnimating = true;

            // current menu slides out
            self._menuOut();
            // next menu slides in
            var nextMenu = self.menusArr[idx].menuEl;
            self._menuIn(nextMenu);

            // remove breadcrumbs that are ahead
            var siblingNode;
            while (siblingNode = bc.nextSibling) {
                self.breadcrumbsCtrl.removeChild(siblingNode);
            }
        });
    };

    window.MLMenu = MLMenu;

})(window);
```

Comment: Please use a better title to your question, it should summarize the problem.

Comment: Why stackoverflow so unfriendly? No 'hello', 'please', 'help'. It's our emotions... It's makes us people.

Comment: I did say "please". You've been a member for 4 years, you should know how the site works.

Comment: oh, i don't mean you... sorry. i mean title... when you write title all good words disappear 